# Install Traefik in Docker rootless: 404 page not found

Tags: docker, http-status-code-404, traefik, rootless

I have [installed](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/) Docker [rootless](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) on a Debian VM in Proxmox. I tried some Docker containers without any problem, and cleaned all (with prune) to install the Traefik Docker container first.

Before installing Traefik, I have [exposed the privileged ports](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#exposing-privileged-ports).

After the Traefik installation, when trying to access the Traefik dashboard, I get the error message (in both HTTP and HTTPS):

```
404 page not found
```

The Docker logs displays:

```
<DOCKER-USER>@<DEBIAN>:~/.local/share/docker/volumes/traefik$ docker compose logs -f
traefik  | time="2022-10-12T22:36:36+04:00" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from file: /traefik.yml"
traefik  | time="2022-10-12T22:36:36+04:00" level=error msg="Failed to retrieve information of the docker client and server host: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///run/user/<DOCKER-USER-UID>/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?" providerName=docker
traefik  | time="2022-10-12T22:36:36+04:00" level=error msg="Provider connection error Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///run/user/<DOCKER-USER-UID>/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?, retrying in 258.609218ms" providerName=docker
```

*<CAPS> for edition before posting. Two last lines repeting.*

The Traefik Docker container is installed from the non sudoer <DOCKER-USER> account.

Here is the "docker-compose.yml":

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
      - CF_API_EMAIL=<CF_API_EMAIL>
      - CF_API_KEY=<CF_API_KEY>
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /run/user/<DOCKER-USER-UID>/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /home/<DOCKER-USER>/.local/share/docker/volumes/traefik/data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - /home/<DOCKER-USER>/.local/share/docker/volumes/traefik/data/acme.json:/acme.json
      - /home/<DOCKER-USER>/.local/share/docker/volumes/traefik/data/config.yml:/config.yml:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik-dashboard.<PERSONAL-DOMAIN.COM>`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=<USER>:<HASHED-PASSWORD>"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.sslheader.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik-dashboard.<PERSONAL-DOMAIN.COM>`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=cloudflare"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].main=<PERSONAL-DOMAIN.COM>"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].sans=*.<PERSONAL-DOMAIN.COM>"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

Here is the "traefik.yml":

```
api:
  dashboard: true
  debug: true
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: https
          scheme: https
  https:
    address: ":443"
serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///run/user/<DOCKER-USER-UID>/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    filename: /config.yml
certificatesResolvers:
  cloudflare:
    acme:
      email: <CF_API_EMAIL>
      storage: acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: cloudflare
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "1.0.0.1:53"
```

The "docker.sock" is in the location typed in these yml files.
"docker.sock" is owned by <DOCKER-USER> and the group owner is a non existant numeric group ID.

I am not sure what the "docker daemon" is (*docker.service* or *docker.socket*), but the Docker service is running:

```
<DOCKER-USER>@<DEBIAN>:~/.local/share/docker/volumes/traefik$ systemctl --user status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine (Rootless)
     Loaded: loaded (/home/<DOCKER-USER>/.config/systemd/user/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-10-10 21:40:12 +04; 2 days ago
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com/go/rootless/
   Main PID: 440 (rootlesskit)
      Tasks: 115
     Memory: 442.6M
        CPU: 5min 29.704s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-<DOCKER-USER-UID>.slice/user@<DOCKER-USER-UID>.service/app.slice/docker.service
             ├─ 440 rootlesskit --net=slirp4netns --mtu=65520 --slirp4netns-sandbox=auto --slirp4netns-seccomp=auto --disable-host-loopback --port-driver=built>
             ├─ 453 /proc/self/exe --net=slirp4netns --mtu=65520 --slirp4netns-sandbox=auto --slirp4netns-seccomp=auto --disable-host-loopback --port-driver=bu>
             ├─ 472 slirp4netns --mtu 65520 -r 3 --disable-host-loopback --enable-sandbox --enable-seccomp 453 tap0
             ├─ 480 dockerd
             ├─ 503 containerd --config /run/user/<DOCKER-USER-UID>/docker/containerd/containerd.toml --log-level info
             ├─3657 fuse-overlayfs -o lowerdir=/home/<DOCKER-USER>/.local/share/docker/fuse-overlayfs/l/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:/home/<DOCKER-USER>/.local/share>
             ├─3665 /usr/bin/rootlesskit-docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 443 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 443
             ├─3671 docker-proxy -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 443 -host-ip 127.0.0.1 -host-port 443 -proto tcp
             ├─3680 /usr/bin/rootlesskit-docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 443 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 443
             ├─3687 docker-proxy -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 443 -host-ip ::1 -host-port 443 -proto tcp
             ├─3700 /usr/bin/rootlesskit-docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 80 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 80
             ├─3706 docker-proxy -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 80 -host-ip 127.0.0.1 -host-port 80 -proto tcp
             ├─3715 /usr/bin/rootlesskit-docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 80 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 80
             ├─3721 docker-proxy -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 80 -host-ip ::1 -host-port 80 -proto tcp
             └─3738 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -address /run/user/10>

oct. 12 22:35:40 <DEBIAN> dockerd-rootless.sh[480]: time="2022-10-12T22:35:40.516184794+04:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
oct. 12 22:35:40 <DEBIAN> dockerd-rootless.sh[503]: time="2022-10-12T22:35:40.517352173+04:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=XXXXXXX>
oct. 12 22:35:40 <DEBIAN> dockerd-rootless.sh[503]: time="2022-10-12T22:35:40.517386322+04:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
oct. 12 22:35:40 <DEBIAN> dockerd-rootless.sh[503]: time="2022-10-12T22:35:40.529791839+04:00" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2022-10-12T22:35:40+04:>
oct. 12 22:36:36 <DEBIAN> dockerd-rootless.sh[480]: time="2022-10-12T22:36:36.203256215+04:00" level=warning msg="Security options with `:` as a separator are de>
oct. 12 22:36:36 <DEBIAN> dockerd-rootless.sh[503]: time="2022-10-12T22:36:36.346784157+04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\>
oct. 12 22:36:36 <DEBIAN> dockerd-rootless.sh[503]: time="2022-10-12T22:36:36.346843512+04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdow>
oct. 12 22:36:36 <DEBIAN> dockerd-rootless.sh[503]: time="2022-10-12T22:36:36.346855302+04:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"...">
oct. 12 22:36:36 <DEBIAN> dockerd-rootless.sh[503]: time="2022-10-12T22:36:36.347114150+04:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/.ro>
oct. 12 22:36:36 <DEBIAN> dockerd-rootless.sh[3782]: time="2022-10-12T22:36:36+04:00" level=info msg="skipping firewalld management for rootless mode"
```

I am stuck here and would gladly accept any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

My "traefik.yml" file is for the configuration **inside** the traefik container. So the endpoint configured should be:

```
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

and not :

```
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///run/user/<DOCKER-USER-UID>/docker.sock"
```

because the binding is already fixed in the "docker-compose.yml" file:

```
services:
  traefik:
    ...
    volumes:
      - /run/user/<DOCKER-USER-UID>/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```